# Deleting current unique session id by phalcon?

Tags: php, session, phalcon

When I logout from `cop1` app (project), if I used`$this->session->destroy` :it is destroyed all two app sessions (two apps are logout), but if I used `remove` function it working well eg. `$this->session->remove("user")`.Because its only destroyed relative session user thus only `cop1` is logout. My needing one is deleting all current(cop1) sessions *not only session variable `user`* ? How can I handle this ?

**localhost/cop1/..**

```
$di->set('session', function () {
    $session = new SessionAdapter();
    $session->setOptions(['uniqueId'=> "cop1_"]);
    $session->start();    
    return $session;
});
```

**localhost/cop2/..**

```
$di->set('session', function () {
    $session = new SessionAdapter();
    $session->setOptions(['uniqueId'=> "cop2_"]);
    $session->start();    
    return $session;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to use [Session Bags](https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/session.html#session-bags), in addition to the normal Session?

> This component helps to separate session data into “namespaces”. Working by this way you can easily create groups of session variables into the application. By only setting the variables in the “bag”, it’s automatically stored in session.

Whenever someone logs into your app you create a Session Bag:

```
$sessionBag = new \Phalcon\Session\Bag('user');
$sessionBag->set('key', 'value');
```

And when you want to logout you do:

```
$sessionBag->destroy();
```

Answer (score -1):

I can't try with `session bag` because my current project has so many modules and sessions ,so I have no time for replacing codes . Now my problem is solved by `session_name` but I don't know is it a good one ? Hoping helpful for some like me ...

> session_name lets you give each application [same domain] a different session.

**localhost/cop1/..**

```
$di->set('session', function () {
    $session = new SessionAdapter();
    $session->setOptions(['uniqueId'=> "cop1_"]);
    session_name("cop1");
    $session->start();    
    return $session;
});
```

**localhost/cop2/..**

```
$di->set('session', function () {
    $session = new SessionAdapter();
    $session->setOptions(['uniqueId'=> "cop2_"]);
    session_name("cop2");
    $session->start();    
    return $session;
});
```